# How can I enable typescript compilation

Tags: visual-studio, typescript, vsix

I would like to add typescript files compilation in a VSIX project. I tried to add a typescript file inside the project, add code and save, but ths js file is not created.

thanks,
  luca

Comment: Have you added typescript support to the .*proj-file? This might help...  http://typescript.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Compile-on-Save

Comment: Make sure to click the show all files button in solution explorer. It may be in the folder, but just not showing up in the sln.

Answer (score 0):

- download and install the [typescript plugin](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=34790)
- if you modify / rename an existing javascript file you have to set the build action property for that file in the Solution Explorer to TypeScriptCompile.